# why regex [^-?0-9]+ ignores '?'?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to exclude integers of a String which can be negative.
I have tried this :

```
String numbersExcluded=input.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+"," ");
String[] stringOfNumbers=numbersExcluded.trim().split(" ");

for (String each:stringOfNumbers)
     System.out.println(each);
```

but there is this when I give input like "aaa-4aaa5aaa?" the printing loop, prints

```
-4
5
?
```

why is `?` included? how can I fix this?

Comment: You have `?` in negated character class so it will obviously skip `?` in replacement.

Comment: Your string says "Replace stuff that is not a minus, a question mark or a digit with a space". The question mark is in your exclusion list.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I meant "once or never" occurance by ? sign . then whats an alternative?

Comment: Inside a character class, `?` does not have that meaning. I think a clearer alternative would be not to use split but rather a loop with `Matcher` and `find`.

Comment: @chuck2002 It will also allow strings like `---`. I think the OP wants to keep only strings that start with an optional minus followed by digits.

Comment: Why not just match things that *are* numbers?

Comment: @kaya3 how can I do that?

Comment: Well, match `-?[0-9]+` for example, instead of negating the character class. That should be a lot easier than matching the parts you don't want in order to delete them.

Comment: thanks, grateful to all your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think replaceAll is not the correct choice here, I would suggest to use :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("aaa-4aaa5aaa?");
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    result.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group()));
}
```

Or from Java-9+ you can use :

```
List<Integer> result = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+")
        .matcher("aaa-4aaa5aaa?")
        .results()
        .map(MatchResult::group)
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Outputs**

```
[-4, 5]
```

Comment: This will remove all non-numbers, whether or not preceded with a `-`. The OP wishes to keep all numbers with or without a `-`.

Comment: I'd suggest keeping the `[0-9]` class rather than `\d`, since the latter matches anything Unicode considers to be a digit, most of which won't be valid for `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: I agree @kaya3, but that for maximum security, I like \d as it is simple and clear.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by security; allowing the user to cause a `NumberFormatException` to be thrown certainly can't improve the security of your application, but could degrade it if you're expecting the operation to always complete successfully.

Comment: thanks for your help